# path.stroke() is crashing

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a **Swift 4.2 iOS app**.

I am drawing a path using below code. It works perfectly when VC gets pushed but if I navigate back to this VC *(pop in navigationController)* **path.stroke()** is crashing.

```
override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    drawGauge()
}

public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    drawGauge()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    drawGauge()
}

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    drawGauge()
}



 func drawGauge() {
        layer.sublayers = []
        drawSmartArc()
        drawNeedle()
        drawNeedleCircle()
    }

func drawSmartArc() {
    var angles = getAllAngles()
    let arcColors = colorCodes.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)

    var arcs = [ArcModel(startAngle: angles[0],
                         endAngle: angles.last!,
                         strokeColor: _shadowColor,
                         arcCap: CGLineCap.round,
                         center:CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: (bounds.height / 2)+5))]

    for index in 0..<arcColors.count {
        let arc = ArcModel(startAngle: angles[index], endAngle: angles[index+1],
                           strokeColor: UIColor(hex: arcColors[index]),
                           arcCap: CGLineCap.butt,
                           center: center)
        arcs.append(arc)
    }
    arcs.rearrange(from: arcs.count-1, to: 2)
    arcs[1].arcCap = self.capStyle
    arcs[2].arcCap = self.capStyle
    for i in 0..<arcs.count {
        createArcWith(startAngle: arcs[i].startAngle, endAngle: arcs[i].endAngle, arcCap: arcs[i].arcCap, strokeColor: arcs[i].strokeColor, center: arcs[i].center)
    }

    if blinkAnimate {
        blink()
    }
}

func createArcWith(startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, arcCap: CGLineCap, strokeColor: UIColor, center:CGPoint) {
        // 1
        let center = center
        let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2 - self.frame.width/10
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = self.frame.width/5
        // 2
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: startAngle,
                                endAngle: endAngle,
                                clockwise: true)
        // 3
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.lineCapStyle = arcCap
        strokeColor.setStroke()

        do {
            try path.stroke() //CRASHING WHEN NAVIGATING BACK TO THIS VC

        } catch let error {
            Log.b(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6b00000038)

I tried using try but it shows:

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression. 
>   'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: where did u call that method `createArcWith` in VC ?

Comment: @McDonal_11 I edited the question. Kindly check now

Comment: You are trying to draw in layoutSubviews. That’s wrong.

Comment: Don't draw in `init` and don't draw in `layoutSubviews`. And don't manipulate the layers in the drawing code, i.e. remove `layer.sublayers = []`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just draw a path at some point in your app's execution. The drawing context needs to be set to a particular context. Usually you do drawing commands in a view's `draw(_:)` method, where the context is set for you. Failing that, you would need to set the graphics context yourself before drawing (Which is **very** unusual.)

How/where is your createArcWith() function called?